# A newbie's question about Component Blueprints

Tags: lightning-web-components

Brand Button can be found in the blueprints and in the component library (1 identical button, 2 different sources):

- https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/buttons/
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button/example

I understand that the component library is here to simplify our work so that we don't have to build the components from the ground up, but we can simply use one from the library. What I don't understand is that why do the blueprints only contain the classes' names? E.g.

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button_brand">Brand Button</button>
```

The slds-button slds-button_brand is a class that is then used in the CSS file for the component to render it the way it should look.

Why don't we have access to the CSS blueprints, but only to the classes' names? What is the use of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [download SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/downloads/) if you want to or review the CSS directly in [GitHub](https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system).

The CSS is only part of creating functioning code, and Salesforce have combined the blueprint CSS with the required JavaScript to create ready to use components as you have discovered.

So if the `lightning-` component exists, generally you should use that. (For a simple button the component adds little, but for other cases the component can add a lot.) If it does not, you can use the raw SLDS CSS class names in your own component, benefitting from the good SLDS documentation.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, this really helped! Also would it be correct to say that a third option is as you mentioned downloading the SLDS from GitHub and then working with the "whole package" (css, javascript etc.) to customize my component?

Comment: Hi @DevelBase2, If you are building within the SF platform SLDS and all the `lightning-` components are automatically available. Your job is typically to build your businges logic using a mix of `lightning-` components and your own code typically also created as components.

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot and enjoy the weekend Keith!

Comment: remember to accept the answer if it helped. Cheers

Comment: @glls Accepted.